# How do I style ExpansionTile

Tags: flutter

Check my current situation here [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgEcg.jpg)

This is the code responsible for the "Select Region" menu

```
Container(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5, left: 12, right: 12),
          child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
              validator: (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return "Please select a Region";
                }
                return null;
              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: green, width: 2.0),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                ),
                labelText: 'Select Region',
                contentPadding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
              ),
              value: _regions,
              items: _constants.regions.map((e) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(e), value: e);
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _regions = value;
                });
              }),
        ),
```

My aim is I want to tweak the expandable widget to look like the rest of the form. This is the code producing the Select Product form. The ExpansionTile doesn't have the InputDecoration widget when the decoration property is called...

```
 Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
          child: ExpansionTile(
            backgroundColor: green,
            key: GlobalKey(),
            title: Text(
              'Select Product',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            children: <Widget>[....]
```

Any help, to work around this code or a new approach is welcomed...

This is what I want to achieve at the end of the day [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bea4.jpg)

Comment: Try formatting your code above so it's more readable for us to help out.

Comment: I just did please

Answer (score 0):

I assume you already placed all of your expandable widgets in a parent column widget.

You're probably doing too much code up there. Flutter has a widget type called ExpansionTile, you can read all about it [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample).

Also, checkout this example [here](https://protocoderspoint.com/how-to-make-a-expandable-card-in-flutter-expansiontile-widget-flutter/), it's pretty much what you're trying to achieve. You just have to tweak colors, etc.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: It couldn't help that much... This issue now is styling the select product to look like the rest of the form... I want uniformity. As at now, the expansion tile doesn't have InputDecoration when the decoration property is called...

Comment: but does the expansionTile work at the basic level, without any decorations?

Comment: Yes please... It works so I wrapped it around the container widget and used the decoration property to style it.

Thanks for your effort

Comment: Alright. Try to take it step by step.

If you want the entire ExpansionTile to have a decoration, try wrapping it with a container and giving it a decoration. 

Else if you want it's child to have a unique decoration, then wrap the child in a container widget with a decoration property. 

I hope this helps you further. 

Also, if this and my answer above helped you out to some degree, kindly upvote.